# Deleting and creating a Azure VPN-Gateway with python Azure SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I have some Azure Python functions which I would use to build and destroy a VPN Gateway every day. In a first step I tried to delete an existing Gateway with that code:

```
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
import logging


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

    logger = logging.getLogger("azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy")
    logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

    subscription_id ="xxx"
    client_id ="xxx"
    secret="xxx"
    tenant="xxx"
    rgroup = "xxx"
    gateway = "xxx"
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id=tenant,
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=secret
    )
    network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id )
    LROPoller = network_client.vpn_gateways.begin_delete(rgroup, gateway)

    logging.info(str(LROPoller.status()))
```

the result from the LROPoller.status is succeeded, but still the gateway is in my environment. Unfortunately the documentation is sub optimal, so I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

You can use the python code to delete the virtual network (VPN) gateways and also you can add them to your azure function app code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
import time

start=time.time()
credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id="Your sub id"
gateway="your gateway name"
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id )
resource_group_name = network_client.virtual_network_gateways.get(
    "<your resource grp name>", gateway).id.split('/')[4]
network_client.virtual_network_gateways.begin_delete(resource_group_name, gateway).result()
end=time.time()
print("VPN Gateway is deleted with time taken",end-start)
```

**Output:**
[image]

For creation you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network.v2021_03_01.models import (VirtualNetworkGateway,
                                                   VirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfiguration,
                                                   SubResource)

# Set the subscription ID and resource group name
subscription_id = 'your-sub-id'
resource_group_name = 'your resources -grp name '

# Initialize the Network Management client
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Create a Virtual Network Gateway object
gateway = VirtualNetworkGateway(
    gateway_type='Vpn',
    vpn_type='RouteBased',
    sku={'name': 'VpnGw1', 'tier': 'VpnGw1'},
    location='<your-location>',
    ip_configurations=[
        VirtualNetworkGatewayIpConfiguration(
            name='GatewayIpConfig',
            subnet=SubResource(id='<your-subnet-id>'),
            public_ip_address=SubResource(id='<your-public-ip-id>')
        )
    ]
)

# Create the VPN gateway
async_operation = network_client.virtual_network_gateways.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    '<your-vpn-gateway-name>',
    gateway
)

async_operation.wait()
print("Virtual Network Gateway created successfully!")
```

> Note:  According to this [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-create-gateway-portal) a virtual vpn gateway can take 45 minutes or more to fully create and deploy.

**Reference:**

[azure.mgmt.network.v2016_12_01.operations.VirtualNetworkGatewaysOperations class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2016_12_01.operations.virtualnetworkgatewaysoperations?view=azure-python)